# How can I add multiple textviews with random words in every X second? It should keep adding till the activity is running

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation

I'm trying to create an app where I'm dynamically adding textviews to a LinearLayout in every 3 second. I'm also adding ViewAnimatorProperty to each of the textviews to have a feel like word rain.  But I could see only 5 textviews are getting added even though the thread is still running.  Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my MainActivity -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
    gameArea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.area);
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //do something
            createTextView();

            runnable=this;

            h.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
        }
    }, 3000);

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    h.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    super.onPause();
}

private void createTextView() {
    TextView rowTextView = new TextView(this);
    rowTextView.setText("Test");
    rowTextView.setTextSize(20);
    rowTextView.setAllCaps(true);
    rowTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    rowTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));//this one fails

//This works fine but fixed width - 
    //rowTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200));

    int yValue = gameArea.getHeight() - mContentView.getHeight();
    Random r = new Random();
    int random = r.nextInt(gameArea.getWidth()-200);
    rowTextView.setX(random);
    rowTextView.animate().x(random).y(yValue).setDuration(3000);
    gameArea.addView(rowTextView);

}
}
```

First 4 textview appears correctly. The 5th one appears fine but its width becomes half. And going forward, the textviews are not visible. Please help.

Comment: Can you post your code, so I can see what's the issue. Please post both XML and JAVA code.

Comment: Added. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Please upload the XML file and the screen shot of your device as well.